# Injecting a repository in a custom role provider gives me DataContext accessed after Dispose error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2

I am currently building an ASP.NET MVC application and I want to take advantage of the authorize attribute with roles without having to use the default provider and all its tables that are automatically generated.

I decided to build my own custom role provider (my class is inheriting from RoleProvider) and implement only one method:

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
{
    Account account = accountRepository.FindByUserName(username);

    string[] role = new string[] { account.Role };

    return role;
}
```

My controller looks like:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

I am using Unity to inject the repository into my custom role provider class which works just fine but when the FindByUserName(username) is called the error I am getting is:

Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'DataContext accessed after Dispose.'.

For some reason Linq2Sql does not like what is going and I am a bit at a loss here. Any insight would be tremendously helpful. Also, if anyone has managed to do what I am trying to do without using any role provider please let me know. The account table in my database has a column called role (int) and my code has an enum with my roles.

Thanks

Comment: OK, so you inject repository. Where does it take DataContext from? Do you use DataContext per request? If not, you should think about it.

Comment: Yes, it is per request. I have the same repository injected using the constructor for multiple controllers without any issues.